# What is sed and what is it used for?

Tags: command-line, sed

I've been seeing a lot of `sed` lately, and I find it to be a rather confusing command.
The manpages weren't particularly helpful, but I do know that it can be used for parsing the output of other commands.

What exactly is `sed` and what are it's uses? I'm looking for a comprehensive answer covering what `sed` is, what commonly it is used for, and some basic examples/syntax.

Comment: From Sed man page: `Sed  is a stream editor.  A stream editor is used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file or input from  a  pipeline). While  in  some  ways similar to an editor which permits scripted edits (such as ed), sed works by making only one pass over the input(s), and is consequently more efficient.  But it is sed's ability to filter text in a pipeline which particularly distinguishes it from other types of editors.`

Comment: This should be a good place to start a comprehensive answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Comment: `info sed` has a lot more than `man sed`. Then, in `/usr/share/doc/sed`, there's `sedfaq.txt.gz`.

Answer (score 25):

In basic usage it is used for 'search and replace' with strings.

`echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | sed 's/dog/cat/'`

returns

`"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cat"`

Sed really shines when regular expressions are used with it.

You might like to take a look at [this article](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) about `sed`, its quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 5):

**Definitions**

*Unix System V: a practical guide*, book by Mark Sobell:

> The sed utility is a batch (noninteractive) editor. The sed commands
>   are usually stored in a script-file . . .although you can give simple
>   sed commands from the command line . . .

Man page for sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 :

> Sed is a stream editor.  A stream editor is used to per‐
>          form  basic  text  transformations on an input stream (a
>          file or input from a pipeline).

My informal definition:

`Sed` (short for *stream editor*) is a text-processing utility that has been developed at the time when text was processed one line at a time, but remains one of the most powerful Unix/Linux utilities; at the same time, it is a form of scripting language, designed specifically for processing text.

**Uses**

As the definitions suggest, `sed` is used for batch processing lines of text, text files, and piped streams of text. Most frequently it is used for replacing as well as deleting text:

```
echo "stackexchange" | sed 's/stackexchange/askubuntu/'
```

However, it may also be used to mimic behavior of other commands.For instance,

- to mimic  `dmesg | head -n 3` (printing first 3 lines), we can do `dmesg | sed -n 1,3p`.
- to mimic `dmesg | grep 'wlan0'` (searching for a string), we can do `dmesg | sed -n '/wlan0/p'`
- List item

The big advantage that `sed` has over other text-processing utilities is the `-i` flag, meaning we can not just output the edited text to the screen, but actually save the edit to the original file. `awk` flavors , by contrast, only have such feature in `GNU awk` version.

`sed` can take input on the command line, with multiple patterns separated by semicolon (`;`) or from a script file specified after `-f` flag, e.g. `cat someTextfile.txt | sed -f myScript.sed`

**Sed applications and examples**

- [Sed one-liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)
- [Text Manipulation with sed, Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7231)
- [sed - 20 examples to remove / delete characters from a file](http://www.theunixschool.com/2014/08/sed-examples-remove-delete-chars-from-line-file.html)
- [Sed Script - Reversing names](https://askubuntu.com/q/538638/295286)
- [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/85039)
- [How can I delete every second line of a file ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219859/85039)

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a work in progress - it misses more examples about the susbstitute command

---

## What is `sed`?

`sed` = Stream EDitor

The description in the manual page for GNU `sed` 4.2.2 reports:

> Sed is a stream editor. A stream editor is used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file or input from a pipeline). While in some ways similar to an editor which permits scripted edits (such as ed), sed works by making only one pass over the input(s), and is consequently more efficient. But it is sed's ability to filter text in a pipeline which particularly distinguishes it from other types of editors.

The decription in the [GNU `sed` page at gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) reports:

> sed (stream editor) isn't an interactive text editor. Instead, it is used to filter text, i.e., it takes text input, performs some operation (or set of operations) on it, and outputs the modified text. sed is typically used for extracting part of a file using pattern matching or substituting multiple occurrences of a string within a file.

## What is `sed` used for?

It can be used to perform complex modifications to streams of data (usually text, but it can be used also to modify binary data).

Among the most common cases of use there are:

- Selectively printing / deleting lines from a text file using basic / extended regular expressions
- Globally replacing strings in a text file using basic / extended regular expressions
- Selectively replacing strings in a text file using basic / extended regular expressions

These are the cases of use covered in this answer.

## Usage

`sed` reads the input from a file stored in the filesystem if a filename is specified in the command-line arguments during its invocation, or from `stdin` if no filename is specified.

Minimal invocation using a file stored in the filesystem:

```
sed '' file
```

Minimal invocation using `stdin`:

```
# herestring
<<<'Hello, World!' sed ''

# heredoc
<<'EOF' sed ''
heredoc> Hello, World!
heredoc> EOF

# file
<'file' sed ''

# pipe
echo 'Hello, World!' | sed ''
```

## Hello, World!

`sed` by default reads the input file line-by-line; it reads one line, it removes the line's trailing newline and puts the processed line into a "pattern space"; finally, it executes the listed commands on the current content of the pattern space and reads a new line from the input file.

When no command is specified or when a `p` or a `d` command is specified *, `sed` will always print the current content of the pattern space followed by a newline at each iteration regardless:

```
user@debian ~ % sed '' file
Hello, world! # no command but the lines are printed
user@debian ~ % sed 'p' file
Hello, World!
Hello, World! # the p command prints the lines already printed
user@debian ~ % sed 'd' file
user@debian ~ % # the d command deletes the lines that would be printed
```

To prevent this one may invoke `sed` along with the `-n` switch:

```
user@debian ~ % sed -n '' file
user@debian ~ % sed -n 'p' file
Hello, World!
user@debian ~ % sed -n 'd' file
user@debian ~ %
```

<sub>* Speaking only for the `p`, `d` and `s` commands, which are the commands covered in this answer.</sub>

### Selection of lines

`sed` can process the whole input file or process only selected lines of the input file; the selection of the lines of the input file to be processed is done by specifying "addresses"; an address can be (among other things) either a line number or a pattern; ranges of lines may be selected by specifying ranges of addresses.

Possible combinations of addresses are:

- `<N>` (where `<N>` is a number): the following command / commands will be executed only on line number `<N>`;
- `<N>,<M>` (where `<N>` and `<M>` are two numbers, `<N>` > `<M>`): the following command / commands will be executed on lines ranging from line number `<N>` to line number `<M>` inclusive;
- `/<pattern>/` (where `<pattern>` is a basic or extended regular expression): the following command / commands will be executed only on lines containing an occurence of `<pattern>`;
- `/<pattern1>/,/<pattern2>/` (where `<pattern1>` and `<pattern2>` are basic or extended regular expressions): the following command / commands will be executed on lines ranging from the first line containing an occurence of `<pattern1>` to the next line containing an occurence of `<pattern2>`, multiple times in case of multiple ordered `<pattern1>`-`<pattern2>` occurences;
- `<N>,/pattern/` (where `<N>` is a number and `<pattern>` is a basic or extended regular expression): the following command / commands will be executed on lines ranging from line number `<N>` to the first line containing an occurence of `<pattern>`;
- `/pattern/,<N>` (where `<pattern>` is a basic or extended regular expression and `<N>` is a number): the following command / commands will be executed on lines ranging from the first line containing an occurence of `<pattern>` to line number `<N>`;

The selection performed in order to print, delete or perform substitutions on ranges of lines will always include the lines matching the specified addresses; furthermore, the selection performed in order to print, delete or perform substitutions on ranges of lines using patterns is *lazy* and *global* (i.e., each affected range will always be the smallest as possible, and multiple ranges will be affected).

When printing ranges of lines or printing only lines on which a substitution has been performed, it's necessary to invoke `sed` along with the `-n` switch in order to prevent lines matching the criterium to be printed twice (this happens only when printing ranges of lines) and in order to prevent lines not matching the criterium to be printed regardless.

A selection of lines to be processed must be followed by a command or by multiple semicolon-separated commands grouped using braces.

### Commands: print, delete

The commands used to print or delete a selection are, respectively:

- `p`: prints lines matching the specified address / range of addresses;
- `d`: deletes lines matching the specified address / range of addresses;

When one of these commands is *not* preceded by an address / selection, the command is executed globally, i.e. on each line of the input file.

### Examples: print, delete

#### Printing / deleting lines specifying numeric addresses:

Sample file:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

- Printing line `<N>`:

```
sed -n '<N>p' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed -n '3p' file
line3
```

- Deleting line `<N>`:

```
sed '<N>d' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed '3d' file
line1
line2
line4
line5
```

- Printing line `<N>` to `<M>` inclusive:

```
sed -n '<N>,<M>p' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed -n '2,4p' file
line2
line3
line4
```

- Deleting line `<N>` to `<M>` inclusive:

```
sed '<N>,<M>d' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed '2,4d' file
line1
line5
```

#### Printing / deleting lines specifying patterns:

Sample file:

```
First line
Start printing / deleting here
Random line
Random line
Random line
Stop printing / deleting here
Last line
```

- Printing lines matching `<pattern>`:

```
sed -n '/<pattern>/p' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed -n '/print/p' file
Start printing / deleting here
Stop printing / deleting here
```

- Deleting lines matching `<pattern>`:

```
sed '/<pattern>/d' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed '/print/d' file 
First line
Random line
Random line
Random line
Last line
```

- Printing lines from the line matching `<pattern1>` to the line matching `<pattern2>` inclusive:

```
sed -n '/<pattern1>/,/<pattern2>/p' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed -n '/Start/,/Stop/p' file
Start printing / deleting here
Random line
Random line
Random line
Stop printing / deleting here
```

- Deleting lines from the line matching `<pattern1>` to the line matching `<pattern2>` inclusive:

```
sed '/<pattern1>/,/<pattern2>/d' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed '/Start/,/Stop/d' file 
First line
Last line
```

### Command: substitute

The command used to perform a substitution on a selection is:

- `s`: substitutes lines matching the specified address / range of addresses;

When this command is *not* preceded by an address / selection, the command is executed globally, i.e. on each line of the input file.

The syntax of the `s` command is:

```
s/<pattern>/<replacement_string>/<pattern_flags>
```

Slashes are "delimiters"; they are used to delimit the `<pattern>`, `<replacement_string>` and `<pattern_flags>` sections;

The delimiter is always the character immediately following the `s` command; it can be set to any other character, for example, `|`:

```
s|<pattern>|<replacement_string>|<pattern_flags>
```

`<pattern>` is a basic or extended regular expression; `<replacement_string>` is a fixed string which may include `sed`-specific sequences with a special meaning; `<pattern_flags>` is a list of flags which modify the behavior of `<pattern>`.

Most common `sed`-specific sequences with a special meaning:

- `&`: backreference replaced with the string matched by `<pattern>`;
- `\<N>` (where `<N>` is a number): backreference replaced with the `<N>` group captured in `<pattern>`;

Most common flags:

- `g`: forces `<pattern>` to match globally, i.e. multiple times in each line;
- `i`: forces `<pattern>` to match case-insensitively;
- `p`: prints lines on which a substitution has been performed once more (useful when using the `-n` switch in `sed`'s invocation to print only the lines on which a substitution has been performed);

### Examples: substitute

Sample file:

```
A-well-a everybody's heard about the bird
B-b-b-bird, bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a bird, bird, bird, the bird is the word
A-well-a bird, bird, bird, well the bird is the word
A-well-a bird, bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a bird, bird, bird, well the bird is the word
A-well-a bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a bird, bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a bird, bird, bird, well the bird is the word
A-well-a bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a don't you know about the bird?
Well, everybody knows that the bird is the word!
A-well-a bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a...
```

- Replacing the first occurence of `<pattern>` with `<replacement_string>` on each line:

```
sed 's/<pattern>/<replacement_string>/' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed 's/bird/birds/' file
A-well-a everybody's heard about the birds
B-b-b-birds, bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a birds, bird, bird, the bird is the word
A-well-a birds, bird, bird, well the bird is the word
A-well-a birds, bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a birds, bird, bird, well the bird is the word
A-well-a birds, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a birds, bird, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a birds, bird, bird, well the bird is the word
A-well-a birds, bird, b-bird's the word
A-well-a don't you know about the birds?
Well, everybody knows that the birds is the word!
A-well-a birds, bird, b-bird's the word
```

- Replacing all the occurences of `<pattern>` with `<replacement_string>` on each line:

```
sed 's/<pattern>/<replacement_string>/g' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed 's/bird/birds/g' file
A-well-a everybody's heard about the birds
B-b-b-birds, birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a don't you know about the birds?
Well, everybody knows that the birds is the word!
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a...
```

- Selecting only lines starting with `<pattern1>` and replacing all occurences of `<pattern2>` with `<replacement_string>`:

```
sed -n '/^<pattern1>/s/<pattern2>/<replacement_string>/pg' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed -n '/^A/s/bird/birds/pg' file
A-well-a everybody's heard about the birds
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a don't you know about the birds?
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
```

- Selecting only lines ending with `<pattern1>` and replacing all occurences of `<pattern2>` with `<replacement_string>`:

```
sed -n '/<pattern1>$/s/<pattern2>/<replacement_string>/pg' file
```

```
user@debian ~ % sed -n '/word$/s/bird/birds/pg' file
B-b-b-birds, birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, birds, well the birds is the word
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
A-well-a birds, birds, b-birds's the word
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is a powerfull command that enables you make things (remove lines, string substitution, string filtering, etc).

I could give you a list of uses with args but internet is filled of that. Searching `sed usage by examples` bring me a lot of results, the cute one: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-advanced-sed-substitution-examples/