# Sed Script - Reversing names

Tags: sed

I have a text file with several names that are arranged with the First name first, and the Last name second.  How can I use Sed to reverse this order of names so that the Last name is first, and the First name is last?

For example I have lines like below

```
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
```

I would like them to look like

```
Blenheim Steve:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Boop Betty:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Chevsky Igor:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
```

Comment: Post multiple lines of your file and desired result.

Comment: @cyrus, please see above

Comment: That's dummy data right? Not a good idea to put real data in a public question.

Comment: With names like "Betty Boop," I can assure you its fake :-)

Comment: Is necessary that it should be sed?

Comment: For Unix/Linux **generic** question, http://unix.stackexchange.com is more suitable

Comment: For tutorial on `sed`, visit [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \([^:]*\)/\2 \1/' file
Blenheim Steve:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Boop Betty:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Chevsky Igor:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `\(...\)` Default sed use BRE(Basic Regular Expressions). In BRE, capturing groups are mentioned by `\(`-> start of a capturing group, `\)` -> end of a capturing group.
- `[^ ]*` Matches any character but not of space character zero or more times.
- So the combined form `\([^ ]*\)` would capture the string zero or more non-space characters . That is the first word.
- Matches a space.
- `\([^:]*\)` Captures any character but not of `:` zero or more times.
- In the replacement part, refer the group index 2 as first and index 1 as second. So that the matched would be printed in reversed form.

Through Perl,

```
perl -pe 's/^(\S+)\s([^:]+)/\2 \1/' file
```